# Centering Menu Links

Tags: html, css, menu, blogger

I'm trying to center the Menu Links but I can't. ([Link to my website](http://edlpdaniela.blogspot.com.ar/)). As you can notice, the 'Home' and 'Staff' links are aligned at the left side of the page, but I want them to be centered. (With percentage, if possible)

Here you have the CSS Code

```
/*Navigation*/

   #menu {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 0 3em 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      background-color: #1C1C1C;
       margin-top:85px;
}
   #menu li {
      float: left; }
   #menu li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 30px 30px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #fff;
      transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
      transition: color 0.5s ease;
       }
   #menu li a:hover {
      color: #69bfe7;
      background-color: #2E2E2E;
      transition: background-color 0.5s ease; 
      transition: color 0.5s ease;
      }
```

Here the HTML Code

```
   <!-- Here's all it takes to make this navigation bar. -->
   <ul id='menu'>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Staff</a></li>
     </ul>
   <!-- That's it! -->
```

Comment: You won't be able to position the menu in the centre if you use float:left, unless you use a negative margin-left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#menu {
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 85px 0 3em;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu li {
   display: inline-block;
    /*  float: left; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #1C1C1C;
  margin-top:85px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```